# hello, I need to return an integer type for a string place, but due to lack of knowledge, I ran into a wall

Tags: xcode

```
private func vvodAge() ->Int{
    var vvod:String? = readLine()
    if ((vvod == nil)){vvod = "0"}
   return Int(vvod)
}
```

//i just need to input a string check it and output int

Comment: Ask yourself: What if the user inputs `hello` as the string?

Answer (score 0):

try the below.

```swift
func vvodAge() -> Int {
    var vvod:String? = readLine()
    if ((vvod == nil)){vvod = "0"}
   return Int(vvod!)!
}
print(vvodAge())
```

then type command like this.

```sh
#swiftc foo.swift
#echo "100" | ./foo // => 100
```